# PostAsJsonAsync with unknown result

Tags: c#, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm doing my first steps with HttpClient and C#. I'm trying to post to a PHP REST server and consume its returning JSON.
When I post to an end point that returns 'Hello World!' everything is fine. But when it returns 
{    "key1": "test1",    "key2": "test3"} I can't get it parsed.

This is my code:

```
private static async Task RunAsyncPost(string requestUri, object postValues)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Send HTTP requests
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myUrl");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            // HTTP POST
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUri, postValues);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw if not a success code.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            // Handle exception.
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be with this line:

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Most likely I need to change it to *ReadAsAsync<>*, but I've tried numerous options but *result* stays empty or I get a run-time error.

The end point I'm interested in will return an array of various length so I cannot use a strongly-typed class.

[Update]

I'm using the Postman Rest Extension in Chrome to send two form-data key-value pairs to the same URL and Postman is returning the correct values. So I'm assuming my PHP REST server is OK.

This is my calling method:

```
public void TestPost()
{
    RunAsyncPost("api/postTest/", new { question_8 = "foo", question_9 = "bar" }).Wait();
}
```

Comment: What do you want to parse it to?

Comment: I'm using the Postman Rest Extension in Chrome to send two form-data key-value pairs to the same URL and Postman is returning the correct values. My postValues are new { question_8 = "foo", question_9 = "bar" }. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your return values are of length N, which is only known at run-time, you have two choices (I'm going to be using [*Json.NET*](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for deserializing):

1. Parse the returned json into a `dynamic` object. Use this if the keys are known to you at compile-time:

   ```
   var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   // Deserialize to a dynamic object
   var dynamicJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

   // Access keys as if they were members of a strongly typed class.
   // Binding will only happen at run-time.
   Console.WriteLine(dynamicJson.key1);
   Console.WriteLine(dynamicJson.key2);
   ```
2. Parse the returned json into a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, in this case it would be a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

   ```
   var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionary)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
   }
   ```

As a side note, doing this:

```
RunAsyncPost("api/postTest/", new { question_8 = "foo", question_9 = "bar" }).Wait();
```

Is an anti-pattern in `async-await`. [You shouldn't expose sync wrappers over asynchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). Instead, call a synchronous API such as the one provided by `WebClient`.

Comment: Thanks Yuval for this quick and well explained sample.
I've tried both options, but I will use option 2. But at this moment json is empty so I'm doing something else wrong. I need to investigate that first.
I also looked at your anti-pattern, but that is too difficult for me. My TestPost is a unit test and I'm using what MS suggested on their site. I'm not sure how to change it.